# Serialization error while publishing the content using DD4T TBB's

Tags: dynamic, tridion, tridion-2011, tridion2009, dd4t

We rebuilt the DD4T TBBs from source control and deployed them to tridion using TCMUploadAssembly.exe.

We Created a simple component with a multimedia link field ,a component link field and a text field and populated the values.  Then created a CT with [Generate dynamic component, Publish binaries for component ] TBB’s inside it  and tried to publish a single DCP.

We are able to run the CT against component in template builder and get the expected output [ i.e well formatted Serialized component XML output]

However when publishing we get a serialization error.  (see below) . This error is occurring while the code is trying to serialize any component field (text/multimedia/component link etc)

We are unable to identify the root cause. Tried to remote debug the code , even though all the dynamic.component object properties are correctly set while serializing the component object we are facing this issue. Even tried to restart COM +, publisher services but issue still persists. Any pointers is highly appreciated.

**Couldn’t able to find why the code is running correctly in Template builder without serialization errors but failing at publish time with below error.**

Here’s the error message:

> There was an error generating the XML document.
>
> There was an error generating the XML document.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Component: Templating
>
> Errorcode: 0
>
> User: NORD\DWTMTSUser
>
> StackTrace Information Details:
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterField.XSArrayInfo.get_Item(Object a, Int32 i)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterField.Write13_Field(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterField.Write14_Field(Object o)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o)
>
> at DD4T.ContentModel.SerializableDictionary`3.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) in D:\DW-Source\Mainline\Src\DD4T\DD4T.ContentModel\SerializableDictionary.cs:line 80
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, String name, String ns, Boolean isNullable, Boolean wrapped)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write13_Component(String n, String ns, Component o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType) in :line 0
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write32_Component(Object o) in :line 0
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ComponentSerializer.Serialize(Object objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer) in :line 0
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
>
> at DD4T.Templates.Base.BaseComponentTemplate.Transform(Engine engine, Package package) in D:\DW-Source\Mainline\Src\DD4T\DD4T.Templates.Base\BaseComponentTemplate.cs:line 88
>
> at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
>
> at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)
>
> at Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine __engine, Package __package)
>
> at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
>
> at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did Quirijn's answer help you? https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/K0BzzPovUz4/1RvTHFHktukJ

Also, if you have multiple publishers make sure you you add the DD4T.Templates.Base.dll to the GAC of all your publishers. (If you've gone for option 2 of Q's answer)

Comment: GAC 'ing of DD4T dll's  (DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.dll,DD4T.ContentModel.dll,DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers.dll) and uploading of DD4T.Templates.dll  worked out !!!

Uploading of ILMerged DD4T.Templates.merged.dll is still  throwing serilization error at publish time. We are figuring out the solution for the same.

Thanks a lot for help :)